# Apply a function on array of values inside Haxe macro

Tags: macros, haxe

I generate an array of `Int` inside Haxe macro and would like to apply a function on it like this:

```
typedef ComponentIdArray = Array<Int>;

class MyMacros {
    // Each descendant of 'Component' has static member 'id_'
    // Convert array of classes to corresponding indices
    public static macro function classesToIndices(indexClasses:Array<ExprOf<Class<Component>>>) {
        var ixs = [for (indexClass in indexClasses) {macro $indexClass.id_ ;}];
        return macro $a{ixs};
    }

    public static macro function allOf(indexClasses:Array<ExprOf<Class<Component>>>) {
        var indices = macro Matcher.classesToIndices($a{indexClasses});
        // FIXME
        // FIXME 'distinct' is a function from thx.core -- DOES NOT WORK
        //var indices2 = macro ($a{indices}.distinct());
        return macro MyMacros.allOfIndices($indices);
    }


    public static function allOfIndices(indices:ComponentIdArray) {
        trace(indices);
        //... normal function
        // currently I call indices.distinct() here
        return indices.distinct();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class C1 extends Component {} // C1.id_ will be set to 1
class C2 extends Component {} // C2.id_ will be set to 2
var r = MyMacros.allOf(C1, C2, C1); // should return [1,2]
```

Since everything is known compile-time I would like to do this in macro.

Comment: Do you want to apply the function in macro context or in runtime context?

Comment: Does 'macro context' mean compile time? Then yes! Basically, the reason I would like to do this in macro is that all of the above is known comile-time.

Comment: While the answer is probably solved, This article might also help http://code.haxe.org/category/macros/build-arrays.html

Comment: Mark, thank you contributions! I have actually used that article as a starting point to generate my array of values. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KevinResoL's answer is basically correct, except it seems you want `distinct()` to be executed at compile-time (as you can see in try.haxe's output tab, the generated JS code contains the `thx.Arrays.distinct()` call).

The easiest solution is probably to call `distinct()` right away in `allOf()`:

```
using haxe.macro.ExprTools;

public static macro function allOf(indexClasses:Array<ExprOf<Class<Component>>>) {
    indexClasses = indexClasses.distinct(function(e1, e2) {
        return e1.toString() == e2.toString();
    });
    var indices = macro Matcher.classesToIndices($a{indexClasses});
    return macro MyMacros.allOfIndices($indices);
}
```

As you can see, you also need to define a custom `predicate` for `distinct()`, since you're comparing expressions - by default it uses a simple equality check (`==`), which isn't good enough.

The generated code looks like this (if the `id_` variables are declared `inline`):

```
var r = MyMacros.allOfIndices([1, 2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.distinct()` is only available when you have `using thx.Arrays` in the module calling the function.
When you generate the expression with macro, you cannot guarantee the callsite has the `using` in place. So you should use the static call instead:

This should work for your code:

```
public static macro function allOf(indexClasses:Array<ExprOf<Class<Component>>>) {
    var indices = macro Matcher.classesToIndices($a{indexClasses});
    var e = macro $a{indices}; // putting $a{} directly in function call will be reified as argument list, so we store the expression first
    return macro thx.Arrays.distinct($e);
}
```

Also see this working example on try haxe: http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#9B5d6